# A website can start in a determinate div when load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A website can start in a determinate div when load?
I make three divs like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbvojR).
and I want to start on the second div when the website load.
How I can do it?

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

html>body .content {
  height:auto;
}

#one {
  background:  #ff4444;
}

#two {
  background:  #ff5555;
}

#three {
  background: #ff6666;
}
```

```html
<div class='content' id='one'></div>
<div class='content' id='two'></div>
<div class='content' id='three'></div>
```

Comment: 1.) You can change the order of the divs. 2.) You can use js/jQuery to show that div with use of `scrollTop`. etc.

Comment: When the website load i want to see the second div, then it can scroll down or top to see the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use smooth animation to scroll to the div using `animate`:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#two").offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q1d3dc7w/1/).

**EDIT**

Without Animation:

```
document.location.href="#two";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q1d3dc7w/2/)

Comment: is possible do it without animations? because in the two examples of code i see how the website scrolls down

Answer (score 1):

You need to use #two (id of the second div) in the url.

like [this](http://example.com#two)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to scroll the second div into view on load:

```
$(function() {
    $("#two")[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```